# Where am I going wrong with my SQL query?

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, pgadmin-4

I'm getting this error `error: null value in column "reimb_amount" violates not-null constraint`

All my columns are actually returning null. `detail:
   'Failing row contains (23, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).',`

but in my Postman I am making sure I have all the columns filled in to send to the database like this.

```
{
"reimb_amount": 400,
"reimb_submitted": {{$timestamp}},
"reimb_resolved": {{$timestamp}},
"reimb_description": "Travel to Alaska",
"reimb_author": 8,
"reimb_resolver": 1,
"reimb_status_id": 1,
"reimb_type_id": 2
}
```

My DAO looks like this

```
//  * @param reimbursement
export async function createReimbursement(reimbursement: 
 ReimbRequest): Promise<number> {
const client = await connectionPool.connect();
  try {
    const res = await client.query(
    `INSERT INTO expense_reimbursement.ers_reimbursement
      (reimb_amount, reimb_submitted, reimb_description, reimb_author, 
       reimb_status_id, reimb_type_id )
       VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
       RETURNING reimb_id`,[
    reimbursement.amount,
    reimbursement.submitted,
    reimbursement.description,
    reimbursement.author,
    reimbursement.resolver,
    reimbursement.status,
    reimbursement.type
  ]
);
return res.rows[0].reimb_id;
} finally {
client.release();
 }
}
```

If you need to see anything else let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Column `reimb_resolved` is missing from the insert statement.

Comment: I added that column and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just amount instead of reimbursement.reimb_amount in Postman

Comment: Ah thank you. changed it to amount and fixed the rest in Postman.